# If $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ and $|H| = p$, a prime integer.

Tags: group-theory

How do I show that either $H \cap K = \{e\}$ or $H ⊆ K$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: $H$ has a very limited number of subgroups, and $K\cap H$ has to be one of them.

Comment: I can see that if $H \le G$ and $K \le G$, this implies $H \cap K \le G$, and so $H \cap K \le H$, but I don't really understand how the result of the problem follows from this.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem! Rings some bells?

Comment: Excellent hint. +1